# dmtracedump -o error(ERROR: not at start of version (found 'SLOW'?))

Tags: android

```
dmtracedump  -o C:\Users\hasee\AppData\Local\Temp\cpu_trace.trace
```

ERROR: not at start of version (found 'SLOW?)

why got this error,but,when I use android monitor tool to create trace file,dmtracedump can work success

(my english is poor)

Answer (score -1):

I found if i use Genymotion that error will occur,my phone is ok